# Java List of ArrayList initializing

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I wrote the following code

```
List<List<String>> vectors = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    for(int l = 0;l<10;l++){
        List<String> v = new ArrayList<String>();
        vectors.add(v);
    }
```

It's works just fine , but is this a good way for initializing a List?

Note : I would really love to know why there are some guys down voted me ?

Comment: Answer is : **YES**

Comment: Yes, except that your variable names are not optimal. Why call it `vectors` instead of `lists`? Also `l` is a terrible variable name because it looks too much like the digit `1`. Also, if you're using Java 7 or newer you could use `<>` on the right-hand side of the `=` instead of repeating the type arguments.

Comment: @Jesper these names are obligatory,and I am using java 6

Comment: @Rifai_deve Java 6 is quite obsolete now, and Java 9 is scheduled to come out in March next year. Any reason why you can't use a newer version?

Comment: @Boann I am working on an old code already exist, unfortunately it's not my decision to upgrade

Answer (score 1):

or one more way..

```
    List<List<String>> vectors = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    for(int l = 0;l<10;l++){           
        vectors.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    }
```

Not much different than urs except it uses nameless objects! 
:)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way:

```
List<List<String>> lists = new ArrayList<List<String>>() {
       {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                add(new ArrayList<>());
            }
       }
 };
```

But in general there is no difference.

Comment: for me it's more clear because initialization is inseparably from declaration

Comment: This is the double-brace initialization trick. You're creating an anonymous subclass of `ArrayList` with an instance initializer block. I don't like tricks, and especially not this one, since it doesn't make it that much more clear and you're creating an unnecessary extra class (which produces a class file, and that class must be loaded by the JVM - not efficient).